# Supressing Windows Alerts Programmatically

Tags: c#

In one of my applications I have the requirement to extract resources from a DLL. I'm doing this by using the command line version of a freeware tool I found [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html).

It works fine, but the problem I'm seeing is that since the freeware tool isn't digitally signed, Windows throws an alert everytime I call it from my application *'Are you sure you want to run this program etc.*'.

Is there anyway I can supress this alert? I'm doing nothing special to call the application, my code is below.

```
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
pInfo.FileName = "ResourcesExtract.exe";
pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pInfo.Arguments = "/Source " + "\"" + filePath + "\"" + " /DestFolder " + "\"" + outputDirectory + "\"";

Process extractProcess = new Process();
extractProcess.StartInfo = pInfo;

extractProcess.Start();
extractProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Any help or ideas on how I can supress this alert or an alternative to this solution would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Being able to suppress these kinds of messages programatically seems like a security risk to me; I hope Windows doesn't allow this!  I think your best path is to change the settings on the executable itself.  Joey's suggestion seems like it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you downloaded the tool from the Web somewhere.

Just remove the `Zone.Identifier` ADS from the file or go into the properties and click »Unblock«.

Comment: Thanks Joey - that seems to work fine. This .exe is packaged with my application - is there anyway to ensure it's always unblocked if I re-distribute it to other users? This is an internal engineering tool.

Comment: Don't distribute it directly or in a Zip file (as the attribute is copied to files extracted from Zip files when doing so with Explorer) from an untrusted source (i.e. Internet zone for IE or a network share). Another option would be to add the site you're downloading from to the Trusted Sites list which can probably trivially be done with group policies if it's all internal.